# Submitting geocomplete form on suggestion select

Tags: javascript, geocomplete

I'm fairly new to JS so I'm a bit confused as in why this is not working.
Basically I'm using the [geocomplete jQuery](http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/) plugin to populate a form with the coordinates and address. Then, once a user selects the destination, I want to sumbit the form.

```
 <form action="search.php" method="post" id="searchForm">
        <input id="geocomplete" type="text" placeholder="Where are you going to?" size="35" />
        <input name="lat" type="hidden" value="">
        <input name="lng" type="hidden" value="">
        <input name="formatted_address" type="hidden" value="" id="address">
    </form>
```

and this would be the scripts I call to initiate the form plugin (which works), and the script to submit the form once the value of the address has been changed by the plugin:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload= function () {
    if(window.addEventListener) {
        document.getElementById('address').addEventListener('change', doIt, false);
    } else if (window.attachEvent){
        document.getElementById('address').attachEvent("onchange", doIt);
    }

    function doIt(){
        document.getElementById("searchForm").submit();
    }
}

$("input").geocomplete({ details: "form" }); 


</script>
```

I don't see why this won't work since the value does get changed. Many thanks!

Comment: A `change` event fires only when the change occurs by direct user input, _not_ when a script changes the input value. Use the events provided by that plugin as described on the page you already linked to.

Comment: Forgot to answer, yes this was indeed the issue, can't confirm asnwer since it's a comment. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post the code you used to make this work? Maybe as a comment to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `change` event fires only when the change occurs by direct user input, not when a script changes the input value.

Use the events provided by that plugin as described on the page you already linked to.

Comment: Could you please expand on this and provide example code? It doesn't seem as though this specific case is addressed in those docs.

Comment: @T. Brian Jones, see my answer below for sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution uing jquery. This forces a submit when an autopopulated address is clicked on or the user selects it with the arrow keys and hits enter.  There is a delay of 1.5 seconds to allow the geocoding library to populate hidden fields.  This required delay is why `'onchange="this.form.submit()"` didn't work for me.

```
  /*
    submit form when user clicks or hits enter on auto suggest 
    must sleep for 2 seconds to allow the geocoding library to update the hidden fields
  */
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#geocomplete').change(function(){
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#find').click()     
      }, 1500);
    });
  });
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#geocomplete').keydown(function(event){
      if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          $('#find').click()     
        }, 1500);
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $(".geocomplete")
       .geocomplete({details:"form"})
       .bind("geocode:result", function(event, result){$(".searchForm").submit();
        });
    });
```